# Algorithm to determine if integer matrix is similar to symmetric integer matrix with nonnegative entries

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, computer-science

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be a matrix with integer entries (treated as a matrix over the complex numbers).

Is there an efficient way to check if $A$ is similar to a *symmetric* matrix with *nonnegative* integer entries?

Partial answers will be appreciated as well (for example, discard the condition of positivity, or give interesting necessary conditions).

Ofcourse, such $A$ must be diagonalizable, and my $A$ is indeed diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer. Let's look only for matrices that are similar to matrices with positive entries (not necessariy symmetric). Some simple sufficent conditions can be obtained.

For example, let $A$ be a matrix of order $n$ with integer entries. Let us assume that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$. Notice that the trace of $A$ can not be  negative. Thus, $\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_n\geq 0$.

A sufficient condition for this $A$ to be similar to a matrix with non negative integer entries is $$\lambda_1>0>\lambda_2>\ldots>\lambda_n\text{ and }\lambda_1+\ldots+\lambda_n\geq 0 .$$

Proof:
The minimal polynomial $m_A(x)$ of $A$ is the caractheristic polinomial since $A$ has distinct eigenvalues. So, $m_A(x)=(x-\lambda_1)\ldots(x-\lambda_n)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$.

Let's prove by induction on the degree of the polynomial that $a_{i}\leq 0$ for $0\leq i\leq n-1$. Notice that $a_i$ is an integer, since the entries of $A$ are integers. For $n=1$, $m_A(x)=(x-\lambda_1)$.

Suppose the result is true for $n=k$.
Consider $(x-\lambda_1)\ldots(x-\lambda_k)=x^{k}+b_{k-1}x^{k-1}+\ldots+b_1x+b_0$.

By induction hypothesis $b_i\leq 0$ for $0\leq i\leq k-1$.

Now $(x-\lambda_1)\ldots(x-\lambda_k)(x-\lambda_{k+1})=(x^{k}+b_{k-1}x^{k-1}+\ldots+b_1x+b_0)(x-\lambda_{k+1})$

$=x^{k+1}+(b_{k-1}-\lambda_{k+1})x^k+(b_{k-2}-\lambda_{k+1}b_{k-1})x^{k-1}+\ldots+(b_0-\lambda_{k+1}b_1)x+(-\lambda_{k+1}b_0)$.

Notice that $b_{k-1}-\lambda_{k+1}=-\lambda_1\ldots-\lambda_{k+1}\leq 0$

Notice that $b_{k-s-1}-\lambda_{k+1}b_{k-s}\leq 0$, because $\lambda_{k+1}<0$ and $b_{s}\leq 0$.

Thus,all coefficients are smaller or equal to $0$.

Finally, by the [rational canonical form](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RationalCanonicalForm.html) this matrix $A$ is similar to the [companion matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompanionMatrix.html) of the polynomial $m_A(x)$, which has non negative integer entries.  $\square$